# Как сделать загрузку на кнопке asp.net mvc?

Tags: jquery, ajax, css3, asp.net-mvc

Есть вот такая ajax форма для переписки:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendMessage", "Order", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "herepls", OnSuccess = "document.getElementById('Message_Text').value='';" }))

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Order.Id)
<div class="messSender">
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message.Text, 3, 70, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "textarea" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message.Text, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })<br />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top:18px; margin-left: 13px;" />
    </div>
</div>

<div id="herepls">
    <div class="messagePage">
       //тут логика вывода сообщени
    </div>
</div>
```

Мы вводим текст в поле ввода и можем нажать 2-3 раза кнопку "Send" и пока идёт ajax запрос оно может отправить 2-3 сообщения, в зависимости от нагруженности метода.
Как этого избежать? Я думал можно как-то сделать как в вк, если вдруг какие-то задержки, то кнопка Отправить становиться не нажимаемой и вместо слова "Отправить" идёт загрузка.

Comment: дак задизейблите кнопку то, в чем проблема?

Comment: как её "задизейблить" на время отправки? по нажатию не пойдёт, т.к валидация может не пройти.

Comment: при отпраке формы дизейблите, отправка проходит после успешной валидации. это в `AjaxOptions.OnBegin` и обратно в `OnComplete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как подсказал "teran" из комментариев:

> при отпраке формы дизейблите, отправка проходит после успешной валидации. это в AjaxOptions.OnBegin и обратно в OnComplete

Вот как выглядят ajaxOptiоns :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendMessage", "Order", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "herepls", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",OnBegin="disableBut" }))
```

сама кнопка:

```
<input type="submit" id="ourButton" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top:18px; margin-left: 13px;" />
```

и собственно скрипт:

```
    <script>
function disableBut() {
    ourButton.disabled = true
}
function OnSuccess() {
    ourButton.disabled = false
}
</script>
```

Comment: делайте `OnComplete`, иначе если сервер вернет ошибку, то `OnSuccess` не сработает.